# Error when creating "Data for ArcPad"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpad

I receive the following non descriptive "error reported on layer ...." when trying to checkout a feature class from a PGDB for disconnected editing.  All other feature classes checkout as background shapefiles from the same database but will get the same error if I try them as an AXF file.  ArcPad 10.2.3, ArcGIS 10.1 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted ESRI support and was able to determine that it was a bad install of software.  A complete uninstall/reinstall fix the issue.